# Countable set of truth assignments satisfying set of well formed formulas

Tags: logic, proof-verification, propositional-calculus, model-theory, natural-deduction

I am trying to answer the following question posed in my logic class: (throughout we work in propositional logic) is there a set $S$ of well-formed-formulas (wffs) satisfied by countable set $V$ of truth assignments such that any truth assignment satisfying $S$ lies in $V$?

My guess is no.  My first reaction to this was to do a diagonalization.  Present $V$ as an array with $v_{i, j}$ the truth value that assignment $v_i$ gives to the $j$-th propositional letter.  Obviously the hard case is when $S$ is infinite; if $S$ is finite, then only finitely many propositional letters occur in the $S$-formulae.  Then there is some maximal $k$ for which all $A_n$ with $n \geq k$ do not occur in V.  Then the diagonalization is trivial: just diagonalize from the $k$-th letter onward, since changing $A_k$ in this range doesn't affect anything in $S$.

But I have little clue about how to approach the main case when $S$ is infinite. I thought maybe I should try using the fact that $S$ is consistent (since it's satisfiable).  If it's maximally consistent, then I think this is simple too, since for every propositional letter $A_n$, either $A_n$ is in $S$ or $(\neg A_n)$ is in $S$, implying that there is only one truth assignment satisfying $S$--since every truth assignment must agree on each propositional letter.

But if $S$ is not maximally consistent, this isn't available to me.  Somehow I would like to show that infinitely many propositional letters do not occur in $S$.  Then I can apply the trick above and just diagonalize through the superfluous letters.

So, yes, just looking for some hints or corrections if you have any please, though maybe if I don't get anywhere on my own I'll give up and ask for more.  Thanks.

(By the way, by referring to letters that "occur in $S$" I mean letters that occur in some formula in $S$).

Comment: Algebraically closed field is complete, consistent, and recursively enumerable.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found my mistake: namely, I believe I was trying to prove a false statement (i.e., "My guess is no".)  [Note: This parenthetical clarification now added to pacify certain exceptionally helpful moderators who "reviewed" this post and supplied exceptionally useful feedback.]

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/873187)

Comment: @Henrik In my question, I asked for a hint.  The sentence posted above is a hint.  So the sentence posted above is an answer.

Comment: @Leucippus Firstly, I am the author.  Secondly, no.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p_0,p_1,p_2,\dots$ be a list of all the propositional variables. Let $S$ consist of the implications $p_n\to p_{n+1}$ for all $n$. What do the satisfying truth assignments look like?