# Infinite truth assignments

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I've been trying to solve the following problem, but I am running out of ideas. The problem is:

Is there a set $\Gamma \subset \mathcal{L}_0$ and an enumeration of an infinite set of truth assignments $v_1, v_2, \ldots$ such that for every truth assignment $v$, $v$ satisfies all the formulas in $\Gamma$ if and only if there is an $i$ such that $v = v_i$?

I tried to generate a contradiction using an argument similar to that one of Cantor to prove that rational numbers are countable, but it failed. Please I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Context please! What's ${\cal L}_0$?

Comment: I am sorry. $\mathcal{L}_0$ denotes the propositional language.

Comment: See my answer to essentially the same question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2438285/ .

Comment: I think this duplicates the question cited in Andreas Blass's comment. It certainly doesn't merit a separate answer.